# Change uilabel text after dragging - UIPanGestureRecognizer Swift

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uilabel, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to edit the text of a UILabel after using wasDragged function of UIPanGestureRecognizer.

I thought I would be able to edit the variable feeding into the label as part of this function, and maybe .reload but it doesn't seem to work

```
var testLHS : String = "+ 2"
```

import UIKit

class AlgebraLearnViewController: UIViewController {

```
var testLHS : String = "+ 2"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 110, y: 167, width: 30, height: 30))
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    label.text = testLHS
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    self.view.addSubview(label)

    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AlgebraLearnViewController.wasDragged(_:)))
    label.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@objc func wasDragged(_ gesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    let snapPosition = CGPoint(x: RHSconstantLabel.center.x + 20, y: RHSconstantLabel.center.y)

    let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.view)
    let label = gesture.view!

    label.center = CGPoint(x: label.center.x + translation.x , y: label.center.y + translation.y)
    gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.ended {

        label.center = snapPosition
        testLHS = "- 2"

    }

}
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the function 'wasDragged' properly called? Is the control flow reaching the embedded if condition ?

Comment: @YashTamakuwala yes, because I am successfully transferring the label to the snapPosition post-drag. Do I need to reload/refresh the label view in some way?

Comment: I think that since you are setting label's text with testLHS in viewDidLoad you expect the labels text to change whenever the variable changes. If that's the case then it won't work. You'd have to give the new value of variable to the label. So after setting '-2' you'd have to label.text = testLHS.